# Fixed modal wont scroll when overflowing the viewport

Tags: html, css, scroll, modal-dialog, css-position

### Issue

I've made a fixed modal to display over the main content of a page. The modal has content whose height may end up larger than the viewport and thus needs to scroll, but its just not working.

### Contents of Modal

Within the modal are

1. An empty *overlay*/background `div` with a grayed background, that takes up the full width and height of the modal.
2. The content itself which may end up having a height greater than the viewport.

### JS Fiddle

Here is a JS Fiddle demonstrating the problem.
I've added border coloring to better help differentiate individual elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/mLjs49ms/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add this css properties to **modal__content** :

```
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
  height:100%;
```

- z-index was not being applied because the position was static so you
  need to add `position:relative`
- and to activate the scroll you need to add both `overflow:auto` and a
  fixed `height` of `100%`
- Without forgetting you should fix the `height` of the modal parent
  **modal** to `100%` as well

**See result:**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: consolas;
}

.main {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.modal {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.modal__overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.5);
  border: 2px dashed green;
}

.modal__content {
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.simulate-content {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 12px auto;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(255, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- PLACEHOLDER CONTENT -->
  <div class='main'>
    <h3> BODY CONTENT </h3>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </div>

  <!-- THE MODAL -->
  <div class='modal'>
    <div class='modal__overlay'></div>
    <div class='modal__content'>
      <p class='simulate-content'>MODAL CONTENT 1 of 5</p>
      <p class='simulate-content'>MODAL CONTENT 2 of 5</p>
      <p class='simulate-content'>MODAL CONTENT 3 of 5</p>
      <p class='simulate-content'>MODAL CONTENT 4 of 5</p>
      <p class='simulate-content'>MODAL CONTENT 5 of 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Would you mind explaining why though? From my understanding, it seems that you are scrolling the **modal__content** instead of the **modal** parent itself.... But then why the need for `height: 100%` on both the parent and the content? Should they not expand to match the child height on their own? One would think `min-height: 100%` would solve this?

Comment: Since the modal contains two elements modal_overlay and modal_content, its only logical to scroll only the content and not both, and using min-height doesn't limit the height of the modal so the scrollbar will not be displayed unless the height is limited and the content exceeds the fixed height